# subprocess.run not able to print output of multiple lines in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using subprocess.run to run a command and print output to a file.

I am able to print correct output for 'python --version' since the answer is 'Python 3.6.5', but when i run the same command for 'java -version' there is no output in text file, but it is reflected in console.

Maybe it's because the output of 'java -version' is spread in three lines!

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys
sys.stdout = open('outputCS.txt','wt')

result = subprocess.run('python --version', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(result.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: `java -version` outputs to stderr, not stdout.

Comment: @interjay yes, in which case you'd want to add `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` as an argument to `subprocess.run()` in order to capture that. After which you'd access it with `result.stderr.decode('utf-8')`, just like you're currently doing with `stdout`

Comment: that solved the issue.. thanks!! @GreenCloakGuy

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

f = open("stuff", "wt")
subprocess.run(['python', '--version'], stdout=f, stderr=f)
subprocess.run(['java', '-version'], stdout=f, stderr=f)
```

Comment: i can not use 'with' loop because i have other methods which are using this line:

sys.stdout = open('outputCS.txt','wt')

as a global parameter to open file to write the output.

Comment: I am not using any loop?.. But if you are talking about `with` statement, then just delete it, and use file descriptor from elsewhere. Edited